# Getting time difference between two arrays containing multiple time values

Tags: php, arrays, time, subtraction

I'm using two queries to gather time values into two separate arrays. I've reversed the array orders and I want to subtract the first value in one array from the first value in the second, subtract the second value from the second value, third from third, etc. I would like to display the difference in minutes between the two arrays. Does anyone know how to do this?

Here is my code:

```
$sql1 = "SELECT log_time FROM log_table WHERE client_name = 'opus' AND server_protocol = '638'";
$query = $this->db->prepare($sql1);
$query->execute();
$Tim1 = $query->fetchAll();
$Tim1 = array_reverse($Tim1);

$sql2 = "SELECT log_time FROM log_table WHERE client_name = 'opus' AND server_protocol = '22'";
$query = $this->db->prepare($sql2);
$query->execute();
$Tim2 = $query->fetchAll();
$Tim2 = array_reverse($Tim2);

for ($x=0; $x<count($Tim1); $x++) {
    $result = date_diff($Tim1[0], $Tim2[0]);
}
```

When I print_r the array values they look like this:

```
print_r($Tim1);
print_r($Tim2);

Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [log_time] => 13:08:29 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [log_time] => 12:15:45 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [log_time] => 11:40:00 ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [log_time] => 09:31:46 ) ) 
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [log_time] => 13:51:55 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [log_time] => 12:29:19 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [log_time] => 12:12:02 ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [log_time] => 09:36:48 ) ) 

print_r($result);
```

The difference should be around **94** minutes. When I print_r($result) I get a warning saying *"date_diff() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, object given..."*. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: `$TimOne` and `$TimeTwo` are not arrays, they're the values from the last elements of `$Tim1` and `$Tim2`. Each time through the `foreach` loop you're overwriting the variable, not pushing onto an array.

Comment: BTW, when iterating through an array, you should use `$x < count($array)`, not `<=`. Otherwise, you'll try to access past the end of the array.

Comment: You need to use `date_diff` to get the difference between two dates. You're subtracting strings, which converts them to numbers by just using the initial numeric part, which is just the hour.

Comment: @Barmar - thanks Barmar. I cleaned it up a bit and just need to do a bit of research on date_diff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're accessing the same elements of the array each time through the loop, and you're overwriting `$result` rather than accumulating the differences. Try:

```
$result = 0;
for ($x=0; $x<count($Tim1); $x++) {
    $result += (strtotime($Tim1[$x]->log_time) - strtotime($Tim2[$x]->log_time));
}
```

`$result` will be the sum of the time differences in seconds. Divide by 60 to get minutes.

Comment: $result/60 = 94.066666666667. Thank you, this is amazing.